# Issue with timezone in Berlin

Tags: javascript, timezone

I'm trying to set a timezone in JS but can't figure out which abbreviation to use. I tried a couple but I might be the issue here.

I tried using momentjs with moment.tz.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Europe/Berlin" would be right here. You can find all others here: [link](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)